using matomo in application and wantes to pass dynamic parameters to Matomodule.forRoot method in angular. getting dynamic configuration assest
Hi I ran into a problem,
using Matomo for analytics and in app.module.ts configuration it needs like below -
MatomoModule.forRoot(
{
  peop1: value1,
  peop1: value2,
  peop1: value3,
})

Also I am fetching config.json from assest before angular application starts up.
Now the problem is value1, value2 and value3 should be coming from config.json but before the promise get resolve app.module external module get initialized.
How to pass dynamic value to forRoot method in this case.
Tried APP_INIT provider but imports modules are initialized before APP_INIT promise is resolved.

please share the minimal reproducible code, how are you fetching the details from assets, please share the code you tried with APP_INIT

Related answer: How to inject configurations in forRoot in Angular module
Define a const that will be empty, which will be populated by the APP_INITIALIZER, you can also define default properties which the config can use here.
export let MatomoModuleConfig: any = {};

Then you can either set the config above the platformBrowserDynamic section, or inside a custom useFactory to this const variable.
Method 1
fetch('./config/config.json') // code from my previous answer
    .then((resp) => resp.json())
    .then((config) => {
        MatomoModuleConfig.peop1 = config.peop1;
        MatomoModuleConfig.peop2 = config.peop2;
        MatomoModuleConfig.peop3 = config.peop3;
        platformBrowserDynamic([{ provide: APP_CONFIG, useValue: config }])
            .bootstrapModule(AppModule)
            .catch((err) => console.error(err));
    });

Method 2
providers: [
        {
            provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
            useFactory: (config: AppConfig) => { 
                 return () => { 
                     MatomoModuleConfig.peop1 = config.peop1;
                     MatomoModuleConfig.peop2 = config.peop2;
                     MatomoModuleConfig.peop3 = config.peop3;
                     return new Promise(resolve => {
                         resolve();
                     });
                 }
            },
            multi: true,
            deps: [APP_CONFIG],
        },
]

Then finally, connect this variable to forRoot
imports: [
    MatomoModule.forRoot(MatomoModuleConfig),
],

